# Magento 2 getAllStatusHistory() after Paypal Express payment

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal, order-status, paypal-express

Im trying to get the Status history from order (after placing the order) with $order->getAllStatusHistory(), while in checkout, paying with credit card, I manage to retrieve the Status history of the current order.
However cheking out with Paypal express I get no data with $order->getAllStatusHistory().

What is the difference between the two methods that avoids getting this data?